# How can I remove plus sign in jquery string

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

How can I remove `+` sign from string in Jquery `$('#sender_name'). val().` If I entered any space then it include a `+` sign

So in my controller I cant get accurate value due to `+` sign (I am using Ajax call that goes every time when I enter a single word).

For example if I entered in text field 'Hello World' then it will return 'hello+world' i want to remove + sign.

```
$(function() 
{
$( "#sender_name" ).autocomplete({
        'search':function(event,ui){`
            var newUrl="<?=base_url()?>login/city/"+$("#sender_name").val();
            $(this).autocomplete("option","source",newUrl)
            },
            source':[]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

When a plus sign replaces a space, that is a sign that the text has been url-encoded.  You just need to url-decode the text in your controller.  You don't state what programming language you use, but all languages have some a function available for doing this.